# Blender Broke and I am very confused

Tags: 3d-view

I was testing out clip sizes for the camera by making 2 renders, one with the objects very small, and 1 very large. I scaled it small, and it worked, it was fine. When I scaled it up, very large, this happened:

[image]

Not only that, I could not see the cube, even when I upped the clip size to max.

Comment: I managed to reproduce a similar case, when increasing the "Clip Start" the object looked OK. Please try increasing the Clip Start.

Comment: Other than a graphics driver issue, I can only say that Blender starts acting weird >10000m out

Comment: Okay Thanks! The Clip Start tricked worked!